# Uso correcto de indices múltiples para optimizar consultas

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, indices

Quisiera consultar sobre el uso correcto de un indice múltitple para la siguiente consulta.

```
SELECT sum(mficob200.cob_imps) as cob_imps FROM mficob200 
WHERE  mficob200.cob_feem >= "2015-01-01" 
 AND   mficob200.cob_feem < "2016-01-01" 
 AND   mficob200.cob_codo="01" 
 AND   mficob200.cob_stat="10" 
 AND   mficob200.cob_coti<>"C06" 
 AND   mficob200.cob_coti<>"C08" 
 AND   mficob200.cob_coti<>"C09" 
 AND   mficob200.cob_coti<>"C10"
 AND   mficob200.cob_seri='001' ;
```

Respecto a `cob_codo` y `cob_seri`, estos ya son indices de clave primaria.

Mi duda es si necesitaría crear un indice complejo de la siguiente forma:

```
CREATE INDEX mfi_cob200_m1
  ON mficob200 (cob_feem,cob_codo,cob_stat,cob_coti,cob_seri);
```

O ya no se debería considerar `cob_codo` y `cob_seri`?

Answer (score 2):

Un indice es mas eficiente cuanto mayor sea la selectividad de los datos de la columna que utiliza. Por eso son perfectos en columnas que son llaves primarias, porque los datos son únicos y no se repiten.

En este caso, si la clave primaria está compuesta por cob_codo y cob_seri, y ya existen índices sobre estas columnas, y estamos seguros que tendremos como argumentos de búsqueda datos de estas columnas, entonces no es necesario un indice adicional.

Ahora, si se diera el caso de que en un momento dado solo pudieramos tener uno de los datos (cob_codo o cob_seri) o bien, ninguno de ellos, y queremos que la búsqueda sea eficiente, si podríamos crear uno o mas índices adicionales dependiendo de los argumentos de búsqueda con los que contemos.

El criterio para elegir las columnas debería ser en base a la selectividad de los datos de las mismas, de mayor a menor. Por ejemplo, si las columnas cob_stat y cob_coti tienen menos datos repetidos que cob_feem, y la combinación de cob_stat y cob_coti es aún mas única que solo cob_stat o solo cob_coti, un indice adicional podria ir sobre cob_stat y cob_coti en caso que no contemos con ningún dato de la llave primaria.

Adicional a esto, siempre debería revisarse el query plan de la consulta, para revisar si el motor de la base de datos utiliza los índices creados para recorrer la tabla.

Answer (score 1):

> Respecto a cob_codo y cob_seri, estos ya son indices de clave primaria.

No estoy seguro de entender eso. Si ese par de campos conforma la clave primaria, entonces no tiene mucho sentido preguntarse por el indexado de las otras columnas: el SELECT primero filtrará por ese par, lo cual tirará un registro o ninguno - y después ese registro (si existe) se filtrará con el resto de las condiciones.

Si no es así...

El uso de índices de múltiples columnas está explicado (en inglés) [aquí](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).

Basicamente, hay que pensarlo como una concatenación de las columnas que conforman el índice: lo cual será usado solamente cuando el fitro de la consulta pueda expresarse en función de esa "macro columna" , o al menos de un prefijo.

En tu caso, y atendiendo exclusivamente a esa consulta, y si ya tienes cob_codo y cob_seri en un índice, tienes varias opciones. Es difícil decidir sobre la mejor sin estadísticas extra. Pero sí me animaría a decir que no conviene armar el índice múltiple que mencionas. Al menos no en ese orden. Creo que funcionaría mejor el orden  `(cob_codo,cob_stat,cob_seri,cob_feem,cob_coti)`: conviene poner primero las campos por los que se filtra por igualdad.

De todas maneras, y a falta de datos estadísticos, yo no tendería a uasr índices tan grandes. Ten en cuenta que la creación de índices no es gratis, lo que ganas (si es que ganas) a la hora del SELECT hay que contrapesarlo con el espacio que ocupan y lo que pierdes a la hora de un INSERT o UPDATE. Por otra parte, los índices de columnas múltiples tienden a ser útiles solo para una o pocas consultas, mientras que los de columnas simples suelen servir para muchas.
Por eso, yo a sumo indexaría (si no lo están ya, y sólo si después de filtrar por cob_codo y cob_seri aun te quedan muchas filas) las columnas `cob_feem` (es muy frecuente que las columnas de fecha estén indexadas, si se hacen consultas por rango sobre esa fecha) y, quizás, `cob_stat`.